# Netlify build fails for Jekyll website: no such file or directory

Tags: jekyll, netlify

I am new to Jekyll and my web development experience is limited.

I have forked a Jekyll theme from https://github.com/samesies/barber-jekyll and I am trying to make changes to it and deploy on Netlify (I just changed the website title). Here is the build log:

```
10:08:29 PM: Build ready to start
10:08:32 PM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
10:08:32 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
10:08:32 PM: buildbot version: 38cc4984170575781fef71bee035f0855939acb8
10:08:32 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
10:08:32 PM: Starting to download cache of 136.0MB
10:08:33 PM: Finished downloading cache in 931.669576ms
10:08:33 PM: Starting to extract cache
10:08:38 PM: Finished extracting cache in 4.991012678s
10:08:38 PM: Finished fetching cache in 5.954914499s
10:08:38 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:08:38 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
10:08:39 PM: Starting build script
10:08:39 PM: Build command unable to start
10:08:39 PM: Error running command: fork/exec /usr/local/bin/build: no such file or directory
10:08:39 PM: failed during stage 'building site': fork/exec /usr/local/bin/build: no such file or directory
10:08:39 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:08:39 PM: Finished processing build request in 7.148101994s
```

I am sure there is a problem with the address `/usr/local/bin/build` but I cannot figure out which file I should update to fix the build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Netlify what command to run to build your site properly - `npm run build`

You can do that either via the online UI, or via a `netlify.toml` file.

More info in their docs [here](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/#basic-build-settings).